# MIRC: Unbind "ESC" key from minimize

Tags: windows, mirc

Really really hating how MIRC automatically "minimizes" my current window -- would much prefer it to do a ClearLine on what i was typing....

Anyone have any ideas on how to change that? i've went through about every menu / option i can find.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Esc::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, mIRC
Send ^a{Backspace}
#IfWinActive
Return
```

In the Autohotkey scripting language should do it - I don't have a copy of mIRC to hand to test it on, though.

Comment: yea - would prefer to do it without 3p software.

could do the same with autoit or even my G15.

Comment: @Gruff Well, alas, we often have to fill the gaps with software like autoit or AHK. It'd be nice if we didn't, but at least we can.

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled by a preference. Open Options (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), go to Other → Keys, then uncheck "Escape key minimizes window."